# Given an input List(1,2,3,4,5), write a a function that can be passed onto flatMap, and return the result List(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5)

Tags: scala

[image]Given an input `List(1,2,3,4,5)`, write a a function that can be passed onto flatMap, and return the result `List(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5)`.

The solution I wrote is the following:

```
object Main extends App {
   val intList = List(1,2,3,4,5)
   def returnTwo(arg: Int): List[Int] = List(arg, arg + 1)
   val newList = intList.flatMap(returnTwo).filter(_ <= 5)
   println(newList)
}
```

output:

```
List(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)
```

How can I deal with the extra 5 in the list, while sticking to the original problem?

Comment: In the description you're talking about an input list of `1,2,3,4` (and say nothing about `filter`), but in the code you use a list containing `1,2,3,4,5`.

Comment: We need a clarification of the assignment as none of the answers (apart from @AkshanshJain's, but including yours) return the result from flatMap, they need further manipulation afterwards. If the result needs to come directly from the `flatMap` it's quite tricky...

Comment: I am not getting the required output .Actucal o/p should be List(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5) but i am getting after implementing filter on flatmap is List(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5) which is not correct.

Comment: `List(1,2,3,4).flatMap(x => List(x,x+1))`

Comment: Re-read the question. You got the input wrong.

Comment: object Main extends App {
   val intList = List(1,2,3,4,5)
   def returnTwo(arg: Int): List[Int] = List(arg, arg + 1)
val newList = intList.flatMap(returnTwo).filter(_ <= 5).init
   println(newList)
}                                                                                                          
    output           List(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5).

Answer (score 1):

you already have implemented the function. Your only problem is the trailing extra 5. You can deal with it by using `init` function, which takes all the element except the last element from a `List`.

```
val newList = intList.flatMap(returnTwo).filter(_ <= 5).init
```

Comment: you can thank me by upvoting and if possible accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This one works well, too

```
object Main extends App 
{
  val input = List(1,2,3,4)  
  def add(x: Int)= List (x,x+1)  
  val result = input.flatMap(a=>add(a))
  println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input list is always the given list, i.e. List(1,2,3,4,5), then we can hardcode a little, which you have done with your filter anyway.

```
object Main extends App {
   val intList = List(1,2,3,4,5)
   def returnTwo(arg: Int): List[Int] = {
       if(arg == 1 || arg == 5) List(arg) else List(arg,arg)
   }
   val newList = intList.flatMap(returnTwo)
   println(newList)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @sepp2k, your example has `5` in the initial list.  The following is another implementation which doesn't require `flatMap` or filtering.

```
def returnTwo (list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  list match {
    case Nil => List.empty[Int]
    case head :: tail => List(head, head + 1) ++ returnTwo(tail)
  }
}

returnTwo(List(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: "doesn't require flatMap" and so doesn't answer the question? "write a a function that can be passed onto flatMap,"

Comment: requirement of the question is to user filterMap.SS attached

Answer (score 0):

```
intList.head +: intList.init.tail.flatMap(returnTwo) :+ intList.last
```